# IOS Mobile APP Automation in Windows 7

Tags: ios, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I would like automate IOS Mobile Application(in iPhone 6s - IOS Version-10.2.1) using windows 7 Laptop.

Is it possible to automate from windows Laptop.

I installed and configured Android-SDK, Java Client , Appium and PDAnet in windows machine.So  now i am able to automate App from real Andriod device in Windows machine.

Now I have to automate that App from iPhone 6S Device from Windows Machine. Is it Possible or MAC is mandatory?? Please help me from this situation.

Comment: why you need Android SDK for iOS? Why the question is tagged with Android tag? Android SDKwon't work with iOS

Comment: Sorry Vlad, I know Android-SDK doesn't support for iOS. Just i told what I have done earlier about android app automation. I need to automate app similarly from iPhone 6S device. Could you Please help me to configure iOS device to Appium in Windows 7.

Comment: Sure, I can. Step 1: Buy Mac. Step 2: Use tutorial https://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html . In other words, only MacOs can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There are applications which allow you to automate iOS applications from a Windows 7 PC. They're mostly from commercial vendors - such as http://quamotion.mobi or http://experitest.com.

Disclaimer - I work for Quamotion, one of the companies that develops such software.